# How do I save and load an image in Xcode 5 for iOS?

Tags: ios, image, save

I've made an app for iPhone which is Flappy Bird-inspired. This app is made just so I can learn the programming behind app-making, and hopefully make an more original and advanced app soon.

The app can load a picture taken either from your Photo Library, or from your iPhone-Camera. I used this code:

```
- (IBAction)didTapPhoto:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take a Photo", @"Use Photo Library", nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void) pickPhotoFromLibrary {
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) takePhotoWithCamera {
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex)return;

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            [self takePhotoWithCamera];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self pickPhotoFromLibrary];
        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    self.imageView.image = image;
}
```

The question is: How do I save the picture which is loaded in an ImageView, and then load it in another ViewController?

I want the user to take a picture and then use themselves as the flappy bird. I have already made the Flappy Bird course, and used to different flappy birds.

The only issue is that I want it to be possible to save the picture selected by the user as a .png file, just like it was saved in Supporting Files. The picture can be saved as a default, for example @"image1", and in the other ViewController you can set that the ImageView load @"image1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save image to iPhone local file:

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *imageName = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainImage.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);
BOOL result = [imageData writeToFile:imageName atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"Saved to %@? %@", imageName, (result? @"YES": @"NO"));
```

Load the saved image:

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *imageName = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainImage.jpg"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
```

Comment: Thank you!
I'm sorry but i'm new to this. Is there anything in this code that I have to change or customize to fit to my code?